# How to upload an in-memory string value to s3 with AWS CLI

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3, aws-cli

I usually upload in-memory objects to s3 using boto3 (in Python). Is there a way, I can upload a string value directly to s3 without saving it on the disk first, using the `aws s3 cp` cli command?

Comment: Maybe there is, but it depends on the operating system, terminal that you use. But you haven't provided any relevant information regarding your setup and how and where do you execute the CLI.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`aws s3api put-object`](https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/2.0.34/reference/s3api/put-object.html) command accepts a `blob` as the content of the file being uploaded.

Alternatively, you can pass content via `stdin`:

```
aws s3 cp - s3://my-bucket/file.txt
```

The `-` indicates that it should read the content from `stdin`.

Comment: For anyone looking for a quick copy & paste script, here you go:  
```sh
echo "testing writing to bucket" |  aws s3 cp - s3://my-bucket/file.txt
```